# Recording output from AudioManager - Android

Tags: android, programming-languages, audio-streaming, android-audiomanager

I am looking to record audio from the device and not from the MIC. I have looked through all the usual audiorecorder and mediarecorder functions and cant find anything on it. The sound that I want would be the sound from "AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC" but cant think of a way to save it.

To elaborate I need to save/record the sound that would be coming out of the device speaker.

Any help VERY much appreciate guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this in Android using the `AudioRecorder` or `MediaRecorder` functionality.

Comment: Is there anyway at all to do it?

Comment: Well, there are some trojans that record audio from the phone call stream: I'm not quite sure how they do it or if it involves native code, so as loath as I am to say it you might be able to track one of them down and reverse engineer it to figure out what it does.